# Does Bundler get gems from the Fastly CDN now?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I'm a little confused. Running `bundle package` of course grabs gems and sticks them in vendor/cache. However, I've always seen them come from [rubygems.org](http://rubygems.org).

Today I ran that command and it started getting those gems from [rubygems.global.ssl.fastly.net](http://rubygems.global.ssl.fastly.net). Has my bundler installation been compromised, or did a legitimate change happen that's now causing bundler to get gems from that new source?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, [rubygems is trying out fastly as their CDN](https://twitter.com/rubygems_status/status/387643971779846146).

Comment: Ah that's it! Thanks, I searched on Google for "RubyGems Fastly", but I couldn't find anything. Didn't think to check their Twitter account!